# Laravel Eloquent Update with foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have some fields in my blade page, named as `field1`, `jedi1`, `sith1`, `field2`, `jedi2`, `sith2`, `field3`, `jedi3`, `sith3`.... etc

**Here's my problem :**
the code below is updating the `last field's` data into every field i used in `foreach statement`.

**In short**, I cannot update the database properly, according the data I got from my inputs.

Here's my eloquent model : `MyEloquentModel.php`

```
<?php

class MyEloquentModel extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'myTableName';
    protected $primaryKey = 'myPrimaryKey';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable =
        array(
            'myPrimaryKey',
            'myAutoIncrementalKey',
            'anotherField',
            'otherField',
            'someField'
        );
}
```

Here's my controller : `MyController.php`

```
$modalInstance = MyEloquentModel::where('myPrimaryKey', '=', Session::get('myValue'))->get();

   foreach($modalInstance as $instanceValues=>$fieldValues){
      $fieldValues->anotherField = Input::get('field'.$fieldValues->myAutoIncrementalKey);
      $fieldValues->otherField= Input::get('jedi'.$fieldValues->myAutoIncrementalKey);
      $fieldValues->someField= Input::get('sith'.$fieldValues->myAutoIncrementalKey);
      $fieldValues->save();
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to clarify, you're saying that the values being set on `anotherField` and `otherField` is the value that you want to assign to `someField`?

Comment: @watcher, the values I get from inputs are the values that I would like to replace in my database using eloquent Instance $modalInstance. Basically, trying to get the value from fields, set them into anotherField, otherField, someField, and then update the database using save() function.